# UIScrollView embedded inside of a View that is paged using UIPageViewController

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

I have an app with the following layout:

```
UIPageViewController (set to scroll style)
--- UIViewControllers
--------UIView
-----------UIScrollView
---------------UIImageViews
```

Right now, the UIPageViewControllers work correctly and I can swipe left and right through the various viewcontrollers.  However, on each view of the viewcontroller is a UIScrollView of UIImageViews.  I cannot get this innerscrollview to respond to any swipes.  I'm assuming the UIPageViewController is swallowing all the gestures.

I searched on SO and found some other solutions, namely to try to grab the delegates for the UIpageViewController's gesture recognizers, but since my UIPageViewController is set to Scroll style, self.pageViewController.gestureRecognizers returns 0.

Here is an image to show what I'm talking about: [image]

Is there any way to fix this?   Thank you!